# Why is this simple subtraction code not working

Tags: python, variables, math, syntax, subtraction

This is a minimal representation of my original code

```
x = 0
count = 0
a=30-count

while x < 10:
    if True:
         count = count+1
         x = x+1

print("count is ",count)
print("a is ",a)
```

This is the output:

```
count is  10
a is  30
```

The a in the output was supposed to be 20 but the line 'a=30-count' is not working

To make it work I have to move the line 'a=30-count'  just above the 'print("a is ",a)'
but I want the line 'a=30-count' in the beginning of the code

I have tried setting a as a global variable but that didn't worked

*Thank you in advance also sorry if the format of my question wasn't right its my first time posting a question on this site*

Comment: Your goal contradicts causality. That is, you cannot receive a result from a value earliest known later on. The only thing you can do is introducing a variable `loop_limit = 10`, so you can do `a = 30 - count - loop_limit`.

Comment: That line doesn't establish some eternal link between `a` and that formula. It just deducts the current value of `count` (`0`) from `30`, which is `30`, and assigns that to `a`. This calculation isn't implicitly repeated at any point afterwards. This is imperative code; you tell Python what operation to do *when*. If you're doing it only at the beginning, then the result is as you see.

Comment: I ran this code in my terminal & it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a procedural imperative programming language and the code is run from top to bottom. When you put `a=30-count` at the beginning of the code, python will interpret it as `a = 30 - 0` by replacing count = 0 to that line of code. So, it prints 30.

Try moving `print("a is ",a)` to the line right below `a=30-count` and you will see that a is 30.

You already know the correct way to make it works, which is to move `a=30-count` just above `print("a is ", a)` because then python is replaying count = 10 there.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=30-count
```

is only called once when you initially call it. To rectify this you should call it at the end of the while loop.

```
x = 0
count = 0

while x < 10:
    if True:
         count = count+1
         x = x+1
a=30-count
```

this gives you

```
count is  10
a is  20
```

Also

```
if True:
```

is redundant as your while loop is essentially saying while x < 10 is true continue.

Answer (score 1):

Python will interpret `count` as 0 and `a` = 30-0 hence the answer. And then it will proceed to the `while loop`.

You while have to move the line `a=30-count` after the `while loop`.

```
x = 0
count = 0

while x < 10:
    count +=1
    x = x+1
a=30-count

print("count is",count)
print("a is",a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because you declared the value of a before you changed the value of count,
So a has the value : 30 - 0
which is nothing but 30.

After running through the WHILE loop, the value of count changes to 10, but the value of a is not updated because it has already been declared as (30-0) earlier.

The Variable a will not keep updating every time the value of count changes, that's why you have to update it's value again.

here's the code :

```
count = 0
a = 30

for x in range(10):
    count += 1

a -= count

print("count is ",count)
print("a is ",a)
```

The Output should look like this :

```
count is 10
a is 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 0
count = 0
a=30-count

while x < 10:
    if True:
         count = count+1
         x = x+1

print("count is ",count)
print("a is ",a)
```

is equavalent to

```
x = 0
count = 0
a=30-count

while x < 10:
  count = count + 1
  x = x + 1
print("count is ",count)
print("a is ",a)
```

Discussing the problem , python evaluates the code form top to bottom. So as the time you set a = 30-count the value of count is 0 so 'a' gets the value 30. As you said the most significant way to solve this problem is by putting line before the print statement
or
create a function

```
def updateA():
  global a
  a = 30 - count
```

and call the function updateA() before the print statement.
I hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

When you write `a = 30 - count`, it doesn't "bind" variable `a` to variable `count`. It simply calculates a value for `a`, using the current value for `count`.

If you want to "save" the expression `30 - count` to be reevaluated later, you can put it in a function:

```py
def a(count):
  return 30 - count

x = 0
count = 0

while x < 10:
    count = count+1
    x = x+1

print("count is ",count)
print("a is ",a(count))

# count is  10
# a is  20
```